# remove part of line

Tags: unix, random

I have a Text File formated like this. And i am using UNIX

for example:

```
192.168.178.65|connected 2/5/2017

192.168.178.93|connected 3/5/2017
```

...

so basically it's always like this

(random ip)|connected (random date)

(random ip)|connected (random date)

...

How can i remove everything behind |connected so at the end it will looks like this

for example:

```
192.168.178.65

192.168.178.93
```

So that I only have the IP

(random ip)

(random ip)

Thank you for your help

Edit:
Just use William Pursells Answer:

```
cut -d\| -f1
```

will remove everything behind the |

Answer (score 0):

If you just need `random ip`, then you can do it by `awk`

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1}' filename
```

Comment: You need to set the field separator

Comment: Thanks. I misread the question and thought he need second field, hence no separator. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cut`:

```
cut -d\| -f1
```

eg: `cut -d\| -f1 < input.file > output.file`

Or using awk command 
     `awk '{print $1}' FS=\|`
or using sed in unix
    `sed 's/|.*//'` 
or (incomplete and not rigorous) 
    `grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'`

Comment: Hello Thank you but then only the |connected gets removed but i need to remove everything behind |connected. If you could help me with this it would be great.

Comment: `cut` removes everything and produces exactly the example output provided in the question.    Not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: You can also use `perl -F'\|' -anE 'say $F[0]'`

Comment: or `tr \| \\n | awk 'NR%2'`

Comment: `sed 's/|connected.*//'`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl script this can be solved,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>){
my @ip= split('|',$_);
print "$ip[0] \n";
}
```

This gives your required output,

```
192.168.178.65

192.168.178.93
```